# In Elixir, Phoenix, how to get session in other module as a module use Phoenix.Channel?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In Elixir and Phoenix, I can get session in Controller by

```
Plug.Conn.get_session(conn, :id)
```

So how to get session in other module as a module use `Phoenix.Channel` ?

Answer (score 7):

`Plug.Conn` is not available in [`Phoenix.Channel`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.1.0/lib/phoenix/channel.ex). Channels rely on [`Phoenix.Socket`](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Socket.html) instead and you can use [`Phoenix.Token`](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Token.html) for authentication.

[Here](http://eafif.github.io/playing-with-phoenix-channels-authentication/)'s a tutorial on how to authenticate channels in Phoenix.

Comment: Perfect answer. It is also important to point out that accessing the session on channels would be *unsafe* as websocket sessions are vulnerable to cross-origin attacks.

Comment: Link is broken as of now.